# Need help Power BI -DropDown List

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

How can we implement dropdown list in Power BI.
I need the dropdown list Eg:- list of company names,Year etc

Thanks in advance,
Chethan

Comment: Do you mean on the dashboard? In that case, visit the custom Visuals page. There is one right there.

Comment: Which one is the custom visual you would suggest? HierarchySlicer? I didn't see one named DropDown.

Comment: Which Custom visual do you suggest for the dropdown list?

Comment: It sounds like you need a slicer? Similar to Excel, where you can pick which years you want to filter by (for example). Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

With the [Power BI Desktop November Update](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-november-feature-summary/#dropdownSlicer), you can now create a dropdown slicer instead of a list slicer using the built-in Slicer visualization.

Here is an example with the Year column:
[image: slicer]

You can click on the dropdown on the right hand side to toggle the slicer view: List, Dropdown, Between, Before and After (the last three are for Date data type).